# Referencing a UI Element from another .wxs file

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I've defined a custom UI element in a separate file, UserRegDialog.wxs to make things a little more modular.

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <UI Id="MyUserRegDialogUI" >

      <Property Id="Proceed">proceedbtn</Property>
      <Binary Id="proceedbtn" SourceFile="images/proceedbtn.bmp"/>
      <Binary Id="headerPic" SourceFile="images/header.bmp"/>
...
    </UI> </Fragment>
```

Then, in my main Product.wxs, I'm attempting to reference the UI element I defined:

```
    <Product Id="*" Name="CRxGUI" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Derp LLC" UpgradeCode="bfcd8325-0025-463a-9589-c4c4713ce11d">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="no" InstallScope="perMachine" Description="My GUI Installer" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate />

    <UI>
      <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
      <UIRef Id="MyUserRegDialogUI" />
 ...
```

But, the wix builder reports an error that it can't be found. With .wxi files, I've just put them in a `<?include myfile.wxi ?>`, but that doesn't seem to work with other .wxs files. What am I doing wrong? How can I reference my custom dialog from the other file?

```
Error   52  Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixUI:MyUserRegDialogUI' in section 'Product:*'.    ....\Product.wxs    13  1   MyWiXInstaller
```

I've tried renaming the helper .wxs file to match the UI Id attribute, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Are the two files in the same folder? You might need to supply the relative path of UserRegDialog.wxs in the `<?include?>`

I think adding this file as a link (visual studio add existing item > select your file > Add button drop down arrow > "As Link") might get the compiler to link the file properly.

Another option you might consider, especially if you are going to be using multiple separate wxs files, is to put them all within a wixlib project and reference that project in your main install. I think you can built the wixlib project into an extension as well and include a DLL just like the wixuiextension and wixutilextension.

I would test my suggestions but I don't have an environment I can quickly check this weekend.

Comment: My helper wxs file is in the same directory. I don't think importing works: <?include MyUserRegDialog.wxs ?>

Answer (score 0):

Once you compile all files, you need just to link them. I guess the file was not being compiled, then you got unresolved symbol linker error.

Using Visual Studio:

Check if your file is set to *Compile*:

Inside your project, right click in your UserRegDialog.wxs, choose *Properties*, then you'll see inside *File Properties* a section called *Advanced* the *Build Action* must be set to *Compile*.

Without Visual Studio:

Check if your build is compiling and linking your UserRegDialog.wxs properly.

Example of a project linking properly, every file compiled is linked:

```
  candle MySetup.wxs UserRegDialog.wxs
  light -out setup.msi MySetup.wixobj UserRegDialog.wixobj
```

Reference:

https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/upgrades-and-modularization/fragments/

Answer (score 0):

Rename your file to UserRegDialog.wxi, then you should be able to include it using `<?include UserRegDialog.wxi?>`.  The `<?include ?>` statement should be below the `</Product>` tag.